# Не работает код javascript, в консоли ошибок нету

Tags: javascript, frontend

начинаю изучать javascript, пишу скрипт, с помощью которого меняется цвет текста по клику мыши. Почему-то не работает данный код, консоль собственно ошибок не выдает. Исправьте пожалуйста что не так, и если что-то не так, почему ошибки в консоли нету? Вот код:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>MyFirstProject</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="first">
  Some text
  </div>
  <script>
   var a = document.getElementById("first");
   click = function(){
    a.onclick.style.textColor="red";
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки в консоли нет, потому что глобальная функция `click` никогда не вызывается.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>MyFirstProject</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="first">
    Some text
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("first").onclick = function() {
      this.style.color = "red";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: если бы она звалась onclick - То вызывалась бы :)